# In Rails - is there a rails method to convert newlines to <br>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a Railsy way to convert \n to `<br>`?

Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
mystring.gsub(/\n/, '<br>')
```

Comment: What do the two / characters do? I use " instead.

Comment: The two / chars indicate it's a regular expresion

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Yes, rails has `simple_format` which does exactly what you are looking for, and slightly better since it also adds paragraph tags. See

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Example:

```
 simple_format(mystring)
```

Note that `simple_format` allows basic HTML tags, but also passes text through `sanitize` which removes all scripts, so it should be safe for user input.

Comment: Thanks- I should have known this- I've used simple_format in other projects.

Comment: It should be noted that `simple_format` automatically wraps the provided text in `<p>` tags, and that this functionality can not be avoided.

Comment: simple_format is security risk if using it for a web app. It relies on Rails interpreting special syntax like `javascript:alert(\no!\)` as given in the reference. There could be endless variations and future variations for malicious hackers to work with.

Comment: since rails 4, simple_format has `wrapper_tag` option that allows to change `<p>` tag for anything else

Comment: ```simple_format(my_text, {}, wrapper_tag: "div")
# => "<div>Here is some basic text...\n<br />...with a line break.</div>"```

Answer (score 47):

You may make it more general by doing:

```
mystring.gsub(/(?:\n\r?|\r\n?)/, '<br>')
```

This way you would cover DOS, *NIX, Mac and accidental invalid line endings.

Comment: +1 for the generalized, non-Rails solution. As a Ruby dev who doesn't like Rails, there are far too few of these.

Comment: Nice regex, thanks. If you want to do something similar to `simple_format` you can split on that regex, use `map` to wrap the strings in opening and closing `p` tags, and then join them.

`mystring.split(/(?:\n\r?|\r\n?)/).map {|s| "<p>#{s}</p>"}.join` should do it, though I didn't test it.

Comment: Excellent trick @BrianKung it was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Also if you want to make the generated html tags safe in a rails view, just do something like this and also you can add a class for each generated item: `<%= sanitize(planning.benefits.split(/(?:\n\r?|\r\n?)/).map {|x| "<li class='collection-item'>#{x}</li>"}.join) %>`. And it works like a charm boohoo!

Comment: Even though this answer is upvoted quite a lot, I want to add that this is susceptible to cross site scripting. You can only do it, if you trust the input (i.e. no user input). Otherwise `mystring` could contain arbitrary HTML.

Comment: The statement about the cross site scripting (XSS) is not true. This would only be susceptible to XSS when the *replacement* string was user-provided data, but it's not. The input string is what it is. You trust it, or you don't - this line of code does not change that. It can't make trusted input untrustworthy (nor can it make untrustworthy input trustworthy). In short, this line of code is not an XSS risk.

Answer (score 31):

You should be careful with this when you are dealing with user input.
`simple_format` inserts `<br>` tags but it **will allow other html tags**!

When using simple_format, `<b>Hello</b>` will be rendered as "**Hello**", you might not want this.

Instead you can use `<%= h(c.text).gsub("\n", "<br>").html_safe %>`
`h()` will encode the html first, `gsub` replaces the line break and `html_safe` allows the `<br>` tags to be displayed.

This will display exactly what the user entered. It also allows to discuss html in e.g. comments.

Comment: yep. like this, it works and I want the output just like input, with the returns shown.

Comment: While `simple_format` allows basic HTML tags, it's important to note that it also passes the text through `sanitize`, which removes anything that could potentially be malicious. 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format

Comment: It's important to note that even sanitized HTML allows basic links. A link can be used to drive users to a phishing site. You have to be especially careful with this if you're displaying a user-generated message in an email sent by your application.

Answer (score 22):

Simply use

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

in your css and text will wrap on line breaks.

Comment: Yeah just simple_format doesn't work to me for edge cases like having various newlines concatenated. e.g. \r\n\r\n

Comment: nice elegant solution that does exactly what the OP is requesting and nothing more - text with html tags won't be rendered as html. in my case I wanted the output to exactly match the input (eg <b></b> won't display the text in bold.

Answer (score 1):

You also might consider what you're trying to do - if you're nicely formatting text that people have entered, you might consider a filter like [Markdown](http://tomayko.com/writings/ruby-markdown-libraries-real-cheap-for-you-two-for-price-of-one) to let your users format their text without opening up the can of worms that is HTML. You know, like it is here at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is just to show the text inside `<pre>` html5 tag.

> The HTML  element represents preformatted text which is to be
> presented exactly as written in the HTML file. The text is typically
> rendered using a non-proportional ("monospace") font. Whitespace
> inside this element is displayed as written.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Answer (score 0):

Nope. What you have there is the commonly used alternative. The definition most people use is:

```
   def nl2br text
       text.gsub(/\n/, '<br/>')
   end
```

It is named as such because it mimics the functionality of the [PHP function by the same name](https://www.php.net/nl2br).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd explain them this way: An answer that fails to take into account something like simple_format doesn't seem bothersome, but one with a definitive "Nope." at the beginning discourages people from looking any further.

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring.gsub(/\r\n|\r|\n/, '\n')
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can do `simple_format(h(text))` – the `h` will ensure any HTML is not rendered.

As mentioned in other answers, this will do a bit more than you asked for. It wraps the whole thing in `<p>`, and adds more paragraphs if you have double newlines anywhere.