# Text formatting with white spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i format text with white spaces?

For example, i write in textarea:

```
      This is first line
           //i need this white space
           //i need this white space
And this is second line
```

Simple_format doesn't include this white spaces and with simple_format, it looks like this:

```
  This is first line
  And this is second line
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your output inside `<pre>`, or `<div style="white-space: pre-wrap;">`.

I thought there was a `<pre-wrap>` these days, but I can't seem to google it up this time.

Answer (score 0):

Use linebreak `\n`

```
text = "This is first line\n \n And this is second line"
```

Or you can use

```
test = <<-EOF
     This is first line


     And this is second line
EOF
```

When googling you can use multiline text in Ruby.

Comment: but this text is writen by user in text_area... i cant just put /n on in

Comment: What do you get on controller when you inspect textarea param?

Comment: description"=>"        Opis dla pierwszego produktu. Jeszcze nie wiem co to będzie ale pracuję teraz nad formatowaniem tekstu dla opisu produktu. To co po myślnikach powinno być wypisane po myślnikach.\r\n\r\nMyślniki:\r\n\r\n\r\n- abc\r\n-abcde\r\n-efghi\r\n\r\nPozdrawiam\r\n\r\n\r\n"

Comment: You already have line breaks in the text where do you want to display that text? - Probably HTML you will need `<br />` take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611609/in-rails-is-there-a-rails-method-to-convert-newlines-to-br

Answer (score 0):

I think `raw` accomplishes  this.

`<%= raw(@mytext) %>`