# Not able to print blanks lines in html

Tags: html

I am using a textarea to store the below text in database.

Hi

Hello
How are you?

In database, it is showing link 'Hi Hello How are you?'

But, i want to print this as a paragraph in an another page as it is showing in text area by picking value from database. Now it is printing as it is in database means in the same line.

I want to print the blank lines as well. I tried using word-wrap: break-word;  white-space: pre-wrap;  word-break: break-all;

Unfortunately, none of them giving the blank lines between the text.

Help on this is highly appreciated

Comment: What are you using on the backend? PHP? ASP.NET? Ruby?

Comment: Try a basic html editor instead of text area.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has `nl2br`: https://www.php.net/nl2br which will convert your newline characters to a `<br />` tag. As this answer notes, Ruby has a helper that will do that for you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/611687/534109

As @Dipak mentions, adding a plugin on the frontend will help translate what the user enters into HTML, which you can then store as-is (after sanitizing it, obviously). The one I have the most familiarity with is TinyMCE: http://www.tinymce.com/ - it has both a stand-alone and a jQuery version.

Comment: `simple_format` is not in a gem, it's in a text helper which is a part of rails.

Answer (score 0):

Replace newline characters in the database with `<br>` tags for displaying in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use linebreak `<br>` tag!
Or make use of this `<br />`
Both of them have same meaning and function - linebreak!!