# Removing "\n" from string

Tags: ruby, regex, web

When I save the output of a bash command (executed in backticks) to an instance variable, the browser, or more specifically, the variable, removes the `"\n"` characters. I checked the source code of the page, and it displays like this:

```
line 1
line 2

line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

But the browser displays it like this:

```
line 1 line 2 line 3 line 4 line 5 line 6 line 7 line 8 line 9 line 10
```

I put this on a method that displays the output:

```
@variable.each_line do |line|
    if line !~ /word1| word2/
        line.sub("Word_I_don't_want", '')
    end
end
```

But the variable won't be compared to the regular expression, and is printed as a whole. The browser displays a string without `<br>` as a single line, but the source code shows that new lines are being identified, but not processed. I tried

```
line.sub("\n", "<br>")
```

but it didn't work either. Hope someone has some tips for me.

***SOLVED:***

Thanks to ilan berci I could print the desired values, although the Tin Man pointed out that text should be processed on the controller. So I modified my method:

```
tempString = String.new

@redes.each_line do |line|
    if line !~ /word1|word2/
        tempString = tempString + line.sub("word_I_don't_want", "").sub("\n", "<br>")
    end
end

@redes = tempString
```

Because processing the text in the .erb was filling the page code with `<br>` for every unwanted line (the `<br>` was casted in every .each_line iteration).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: My rails version is 4.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<% @variable.each_line do |line| %>
    <% line = if line !~ /word1| word2/ %>
      <%line.sub("Word_I_don't_want", '') %>
    <% end %>
    <%= line %>
    <br/>
  <% end %>`

Comment: Thanks! I found this to be the easier to implement. My mind closed to the fact that I can process the text in erb. Do you know of any guide about creating new routes aside the default ones? I don't wanna use show for everything

Comment: You shouldn't process the text in your view (erb file). It needs to be done in your controller prior to passing off the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how browsers display line-ends and white-space. They "gobble" spaces, tabs, vertical-tabs and line-endings, squeezing them into a single space when displayed.

For instance:

```
<html>
<body>
foo
bar
</body>
</html>
```

Will display as `foo bar` in a browser, even though there is line-end ("\n") between `foo` and `bar`.

You can fix that a couple ways:

```
<html>
<body>
foo<br>
bar<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Or:

```
<html>
<body>
<pre>
foo
bar
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

would display as:

```
foo
bar
```

Whereas:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
</body>
</html>
```

would display as:

```
foo

bar
```

Browser barely honor whitespace. Words with multiple spaces and line-ends will display as if they only have a single space. If I had a string of characters:

```
foo\t \n bar
```

in a page, they would display as:

```
foo bar
```

because the browser is trying to be helpful.

How do you "fix" your code? You either wrap your text in a `<pre>` block, append `<br>` to the lines where you want line-breaks, or do something fun with CSS to adjust the defaults of `<p>` or `<div>` tags. There are lots of ways to get there, you just need to know what you're working with and pick a path.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in my applications:

```
def replace_newlines_with_br_tags(text)
  h(text).gsub(/\r\n/, '<br />').gsub(/\r/, '<br />').gsub(/\n/, '<br />')
end
```

You can add this to your application helper and use it in your views, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
@variable.gsub(/(?:\n\r?|\r\n?)/, '<br>')
```

Credits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611609/in-rails-is-there-a-rails-method-to-convert-newlines-to-br)